# How to keep navigation text inline with the end of an image

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a navigation bar and I want the text, which is going to be on the right, to be inline with the end of the image. I want it to stay aligned and in position regardless of whether the window is resized or not.

I've included an image incase I haven't explained it very well:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWR6L.png

Hopefully you guys can help!

Comment: Is your main content wrapper centered? It is hard to tell the layout of the page. If you have it centered, just make sure the `<nav>` containing the list of navigation elements is the same width as the banner's container, and position it the same way (looks like `margin: 0 auto;`)

Comment: could you post the code you have already so we can make changes?

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Axacq/ ?

Comment: Hi Daniel. Yeah, this is what I'm after however, I'm having issue incorporating this into my code. Would you like me to post the link so you can take a look at the source?

Answer (score 0):

Is this something that you are looking to achieve ?... http://jsfiddle.net/65fBD/ Now the way i achieved it is to float the image to the right and wrap the image and the links inside a div and give it a min-width attribute. what this does that as soon as it hits the minimum width specified in viewport, the division will not shrink after that thus maintaining the inline look.

here is the css

```
#navcontainer {
width:100%;
min-width:400px;
height:40px
}
#image {
    float: left;
}
#links {
float:right;
}
```

and the html...

```
<div id="navcontainer">
 <img src="http://dummyimage.com/230x40/123dfe/fff" id="image"/>
 <p id="links"> &nbsp;&nbsp;Link&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Link&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;Link&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

But on another note, please clarify what you mean by if window is resized the link should stay aligned....are you referring to responsive design?

Comment: Maybe I understood the question differently from you, but I don't think this solves the problem. The image should be below the text, no?

Comment: i am going by the definition of "in-line" here... i am not quite sure what OP wants. i assumed that by inline to the image he meant the image and the links are in the same line?...maybe . i dunno if i understood the question right here as well

Comment: Hi guys, I'm actually going for what Dan suggested.